# Populate html template with json data

Tags: javascript, html, json

I need to populate a html template with Json data with a specific object ID.

Let's say my json data is in a file named mydata.json and looks like that:

```
[
    {
        "ID": "001",
        "title": "This is my title",
        "content": "This is my content"
    },
    {
        "ID": "002",
        "title": "This is my title",
        "content": "This is my content"
    },
    {
        "ID": "003",
        "title": "This is my title",
        "content": "This is my content"
    }
]
```

How can I load this file and populate a html template with only the data from object ID 002 for exemple?

Comment: by writing some code ? You should first give it a try and then you are always welcome to stackoverflow if you face any issues in that

Comment: you can not load json file from local. it must me served from http request..
One thing you can do is that by ajax request you can get the json file and read the data and populate the html.

Comment: Load file with ajax ( xmlhttprequest ) or fetch(). Parse json text. Find() resulting array for ID 002. Loop over the object properties to saturate the html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could convert your array to object with ID props:

```js
const contArr = [{
    "ID": "001",
    "title": "This is my title 1",
    "content": "This is my content 1"
  },
  {
    "ID": "002",
    "title": "This is my title 2",
    "content": "This is my content 2"
  },
  {
    "ID": "003",
    "title": "This is my title 3",
    "content": "This is my content 3"
  }
];

const contObj = contArr.reduce((o, c) => [o, o[c.ID] = c][0], {});

console.log(contObj['002'].title);
console.log(contObj['003'].content);
```

Comment: Any reason you prefer this over `Array.find()`?

Comment: @Shilly `find` is quite good, but you always need to reiterate the whole array in search for. Whilst the above iterates only once - and you can get the desired data directly by prop reference.

Comment: PERFECT ! works great, thank you very much @RokoC.Buljan, you made my day !

Comment: Ouch, just tried on this f... old IE11 and for some Reason it doesn't work… Any workaround ? THX !!!